# Causes for java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [services.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, web-applications, maven, websphere, rad

I have a web-application on RAD 7.5. I am building the application using Maven and deploying on WebSphere 6.1.

A part of my web.xml is:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:services.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This is the only place where I am referencing services.xml.

My services.xml is in folder

```
FruitApplication/src/main/resources/services.xml
```

After building with maven, services.xml is in the following path in the target folder

```
target/FruitApplication-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/services.xml
```

On deployment, I continuously get below mentioned error. However, on building the application two three times, it disappears on its own and then reappears again haphazardly.

What is the actual cause of this error ? 
How to solve this error ?

The top of my services.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">
```

Is something needs to be changed here ???

Below is the complete pom.xml I am using for "maven-install":

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FruitApplication</groupId>
  <artifactId>FruitApplication</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

 <build> 
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
              <manifestFile>
            src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
          </manifestFile>
        </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build> 

 <dependencies>
        ... dependencies here ...
 </dependencies>

</project>
```

I have already tried all the below three options:

```
<param-value>classpath:services.xml</param-value>
<param-value>classpath:/services.xml</param-value>
<param-value>WEB-INF/classes/services.xml</param-value>
```

How I am deploying:

I am removing the application from the server by right clicking on server and "add or remove applications"

I am doing a run-as "maven-clean" and then run-as "maven-install" on the application and again adding the application by right clicking on the server and "add or remove applications"

Comment: When you receive that error, do you check the WAR file to see if the file is actually there where you expect it?

Comment: How are you deploying? Just dropping the maven generated war in the container? Can you include your build->resources portion of your pom in the question?

Comment: Are you getting the error in RAD, Websphere or both? As @smp7d suggested use the resources stage and include the path to copy services.xml to explicit WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF directory. Although WEB-INF is not in classpath try it.

Comment: The error is coming after I add the application on the server and when it is getting deployed by the server. So I think it will be a websphere error... right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `classpath:/services.xml`? The leading slash means to pull the resource from the root of the classpath. Without it, the file is expected to be in the package of whatever class is loading it (which I admit I don't know what that would be in this case).

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

1. Select project where the reource files exist.Right click - Build path - configure build path - sources -Add folder - add the folder where you resource file exist.This would add the folder to you class path.
2. If the above project/jar is part of another WAR/EAR then select that WAR and/or EAR - properties - j2ee module dependecies and select the above project to get added to build path.
   Restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out if its Websphere/RAD or a application issue?

First build the war file and drop it in a Tomcat container and check if you still see the error. 
1. If you see then copy the services.xml to WEB-INF and WEB-INF/classes directory and see if it works.
2. Also check your CLASSPATH system environment variable, system CLASSPATH can override your application classpath.

If everything is fine with Tomcat, there is something specific to Websphere/RAD:
3. Check you websphere environment, I recall there is some option in websphere where you can set/override/prefix the classpath.